# Reporting Services URL parameter problems

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, oracle, reporting-services

I have an URL to a location on the server where it can find teh report.
The report works just fine if i manually refresh it.

I tried using rc:ClearSession=TRUE and i also tried sending a random parameter, but the report is still not being refreshed.

Any ideas?

The main scenario:
User eneters the page(with a grid view)
User clicks on Export
User sees the Report
User deletes an entry from the page - grid view
User clicks on Export again
User sees the exact same report

P.S. : The report query returns the data that should be displayed but the report returns the previous data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: it was that the name of the report was too long
I don't really understand why the report would work but won't refresh.
I shortened the name and it worked.

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Could be how the report is setup. Go to your report server (http://reportserver/reports). Find the report and click Properties. Then go to Execution. Are any of the report caching or snapshot options turned on?

Comment: Always run this report with the most recent data
Do not cache temporary copies of this report

The rest are not checked